# i am trying to fetch value from dropdown and want to add new value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to change current value from Dropdown...but getting problem with fetching value from dropdown. on show page current status are showing and dropdown option are there for update status.after click on button i want to show new status.

```js
<script>
    // Update record
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#nextStatusBtn').click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var status_id = $(this).attr("data-id");                
                    console.log('status_id');               
                    $.ajax({
                    url: "{{route('admin.leads.updateStatus',$leads->id)}}",
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        _token: "{{csrf_token()}}",
                        status_id: status_id
                    }
                });                                 
        
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

```css
public function updateStatus(Request $request, Lead_status $lead_status)
{
    $status_id = $request->status_id;
    $lead_id = $request->lead_id;
    var_dump($status_id);
    die;
    $lead_status = new Lead_status;
    $lead_status->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $lead_status->lead_id = $lead_id;
    $lead_status->status_id = $status_id;
    if($lead_status->save()){
        return json_encode(['code'=>0,'message'=>'Lead Status Changed Successfully!','data'=>$lead_status]);
    } else {
        return json_encode(['code'=>100,'message'=>'Error updating lead status','data'=>'']);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group mr-3" role="group">
                <div class="dropdown d-inline">
                    <button class="btn btn-{{$leads->status[0]->colour}} dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton4" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        {{$leads->status[0]->status}}
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" x-placement="bottom-start">
                        @foreach($statuses as $s)
                            <a class="dropdown-item bg-{{$s->colour}}" data-id="{{$s->id}}">{{$s->status}}</a>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-{{$leads->status[0]->colour}} d-inline" id="nextStatusBtn" type="button">btn</i></button>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your click event is on the "next" button, not on the menu item - so `$(thsi).attr("data-id")` will always be null.   I can't see how you determine which is "active" when you click next - but you *probably* just want the click handler on the `$("a.dropdown-item")` not some apparently unrelated button.   You also probably want: `console.log('status_id', status_id);` to see what you're getting (nothing/empty string/null)

Comment: Is your `status_id` empty?

Comment: no....i have data in status_id